# MySQL update table column by after update trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

I want to update `_history` column after other table's columns update in `MySQL`.
I create the below trigger:

```
CREATE DEFINER = `root` @`localhost` TRIGGER `update_history` AFTER
UPDATE
    ON
    `_users` FOR EACH ROW 

BEGIN
IF NEW.is_active <> OLD.is_active || NEW.is_deleted <> OLD.is_deleted THEN 
    UPDATE
        `_users`
    SET
        NEW._history = JSON_ARRAY_APPEND(
            OLD._history, 
            '$', 
            '{' ||
                '"date": "' || cast(NOW() + 0 as CHAR) || '"' || ',' ||
                '"username": "' || OLD.username || '"' || ',' ||
                '"is_active": "' || cast(OLD.is_active as CHAR)|| '"' || ',' ||
                '"is_deleted": "' || cast(OLD.is_deleted as CHAR) || '"' ||
            '}'
            )
    WHERE
        NEW.user_id = OLD.user_id;
END IF;
END;
```

after update `is_active`, the below error occurs.

```
SQL Error [4048] [42000]: Invalid target for assignment in INSERT or UPDATE statement 'NEW._history'.
  Invalid target for assignment in INSERT or UPDATE statement 'NEW._history'.
  Invalid target for assignment in INSERT or UPDATE statement 'NEW._history'.
```

I tried many ways like using `BEFORE UPDATE` or removing the `IF` condition but the error still occurs.

Answer (score 2):

In MySQL, you can't update a table in a trigger for the same table, because it would cause an infinite loop of trigger execution.

But you don't have to use `UPDATE`. Just use `SET NEW.<column> = ...`

```
CREATE DEFINER = `root` @`localhost` TRIGGER `update_history` BEFORE UPDATE
    ON `_users` FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    IF NEW.is_active <> OLD.is_active || NEW.is_deleted <> OLD.is_deleted THEN 
        SET
            NEW._history = JSON_ARRAY_APPEND(
                OLD._history, 
                '$', JSON_OBJECT(
                    'date', CAST(NOW() + 0 AS CHAR),
                    'username', OLD.username,
                    'is_active', CAST(OLD.is_active AS CHAR),
                    'is_deleted', CAST(OLD.is_deleted AS CHAR)
                )
            );
    END IF;
END
```

I also showed the use of `JSON_OBJECT()` instead of the error-prone method of formatting JSON using string-concatenation.

Comment: Thanks. But when I wanted to save your suggestion, MySQL show this error: `SQL Error [1362] [HY000]: Updating of NEW row is not allowed in trigger
  Updating of NEW row is not allowed in trigger
  Updating of NEW row is not allowed in trigger`

Comment: I changed After Update to Before Update and it works for me.

Comment: Yes, good catch. I have edited to fix this in my answer. You can't change values of a row in an AFTER trigger.